# Looking for collection of three short YA horror stories from the 1980s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

When I was a kid, in about 1987 or so, I read a collection of short horror stories that contained three brief stories.  One was about a boy who gets on a bus by himself and meets an old man who is cursed to ride the bus forever.  The boy trades his lunch--a cheese sandwich, I remember--for the old man's lunch, and then the old man is able to get off the bus, and the boy is cursed to ride forever.

Another story involves a town which neglects its  cemetery, which angers the dead, who somehow summon a storm that carries them into the town.  At one point the wind blows a rag into a man's face and a bony hand in the rag claws at him before he can pull it off.  At the end of the story the storm passes but the dead leave a message written on a wall saying "DON'T FORGET US AGAIN". The last story is about a boy whose father asks him to go to the garage to get something,  but the boy is reluctant to go.  Someone else goes and is taken by a creature in the garage, of which only its long, gnarled fingers are seen.  At one point the boy goes outside and can see the creature moving in a window.  Eventually the boy has to go and is taken, and then the father goes to see what's taking so long and is taken himself.  Finally only a dog is left barking inside, and eventually it stops barking and only the thing in the garage is left.

Anyone able to help me identify this collection?